# Resolving ImportError: Module "redis.connection" does not define a "HiredisParser" attribute/class

Tags: django, redis, django-redis

My django project has this issue after I updated my redis to version 5.4.0. It seems that the HiredisParser that I was using in my PARSER_CLASS in the redis configuration could not be found in this update. After taking a look at the change log, it seems the issue is a rename of the HiredisParser class from `HiredisParser` to `_HiredisParser`.

So a simple change from this:

```py
"PARSER_CLASS": "redis.connection.HiredisParser"
```

to this:

```py
"PARSER_CLASS": "redis.connection._HiredisParser"
```

should fix the issue.

Note that if hiredis package is already installed you can remove the whole line completely in your django cache configuration as it will by default select `_HiredisParser` if  hiredis is installed.

Relevant source:
https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis/issues/676